# GraphHopper cannot find route

Tags: graphhopper

`GraphHopper` couldn't find route between two two points below:

```
double latFrom = -19.637121;
double lonFrom = 134.192328;        
double latTo = -37.7988237;
double lonTo = 144.9593481;
```

I tried this using online `graphhopper` demo, but it also didn't find route. Whearas Google Maps finds the a route.

[GraphHopper online example](https://graphhopper.com/maps/?point=0860%2C%20Tennant%20Creek%2C%20Australia&point=Melbourne%20University%20Regiment%2C%203000%2C%20Australia%2C%203000%2C%20Australia&locale=ru-RU&layer=Lyrk) and [Google Maps online example](https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir/-19.6412993,134.1941705/University+of+Melbourne,+Parkville+VIC/@-28.9436467,124.7651739,4z/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x6ad642d45c07254b:0xeacb63e2b725ff6d!2m2!1d144.961174!2d-37.796369)

Is it a bug of `graphhopper`? Can this be fixed?

Moreover, only 2 out of 5 routing algorithms worked (`Bidirectional Dijkstra  and Bidirectional A*.`) others didn't work. What is a reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first problem, that is already [an issue regarding fords](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/236), see [this node](http://www.openstreetmap.org/node/29370606) in your case.

Regarding the second problem: disable CH (`prepare.chWeighting=no`) and you can use also unidirectional algorithms.

Comment: can you specify where should I disable CH?

Comment: in the config.properties with the mentioned settings